# Creating a new user in Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

I downloaded the [Oracle VirtualBox VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) containing Oracle SQL Server 11g and all their dev tools. (There's not much documentation along with it and I had to find fragments of info here and there.) Anyhow, I was reading the Oracle's [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/users_secure004.htm#sthref437) for creating a new user, but the documentation is for 10g. Well, I'm not sure what are the differences between 11g and 10g, but I sure don't see any "Users" page anywhere in the Enterprise Manager application.

Would someone be kind enough to point me where the Users page in **Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g** actually is? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be available under Server -> Security

[image: Oracle Enterprise Manager]

Comment: ah! I guess I missed that one then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a lack of finding useful information, here's what I did. (For posterity.)

1. Optionally create a tablespace in **Enterprise Manager 11g** (under *Server* tab)
2. Fire up a terminal console and type

   ```
   $ sqlplus

   SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Apr 7 20:22:46 2011

   Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

   Enter user-name: <your username here>
   Enter password: <your password here>

   Connected to:
   Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
   With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

   SQL> CONNECT / as sysdba
   Connected.
   SQL> CREATE USER <new_user_name> IDENTIFIED BY "<password>" 
   DEFAULT TABLESPACE "<desired_tablespace>" 
   TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;

   User created.

   SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO <new_user_name>;

   Grant succeeded.

   SQL> GRANT DBA TO <new_user_name>;

   Grant succeeded.

   SQL> ALTER USER <new_user_name> QUOTA UNLIMITED ON <desired_tablespace>;

   User altered.

   SQL> exit
   ```
3. You now have a working new user